# Can I put another button into Jquery Ajax success function so that I can gain better control

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("A").click(function (e){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "/xxx",
    dataType: "Json",
    success: function (rep_data){
        if (rep_data.a === true) {
            ...
        } else {
            $("B").click(function (){
                ...
            })
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error")
    }
})
```

})

I use if else structure in success function, but i want to gain better control on else branch by putting another button in else branch(if is possible to reuse "A" button, that could be better).I try this code, but it didn't works. Could somebody can help me?

Comment: I want to release else branch when I click button "B" otherwise it will not be released

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write event binding on `$("B")` in another event's method of element `$("A")`, as this will result in adding multiple events on `$("B")` with the user actions on `$("A")`, which will later cause discrepancies.

To avoid this, write your click event handler for `$("B")` outside the click event of `$("A")`.

```js
$("B").click(function (){
    ...
})
```

Then you may trigger click event on `$("B")` in the click event of `$("A")` like this:

```js
$("B").trigger("click"):

\\ or

$("B").click();
```